# Need help in proving $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} A_n\lt \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum^\infty_{k=m} A_k =0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} A_n\lt \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum^\infty_{k=m} A_k=0 $$

I don't know if $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \sum^\infty_{k=m} A_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} A_k$. I also considered using Cauchy convergence test, but not sure if that sum can be expanded to infinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, $s_m=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m}A_n$. The expression on the right is $t_m=s-s_{m-1}$. What happens when you let $m\to+ \infty$?

Comment: Thanks! I was being silly.